# bs-datepicker not highlighting current date

Tags: angularjs, highlight, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use bs-datepicker to select a date-range but I am not able to get it working exactly as I want to. The validations are not a problem, the problem is that the **current date is not highlighted** in the datepicker, it is sort of muted. If I click on it then it becomes selected. So the problem is basically when the page is first loaded and I go on to select the date, the current date is muted. I have tried a lot of variants (init-date, defaultDate) but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-min-date="today"
           datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
           data-max-date="endDate"
           required data-autoclose="1"
           ng-model="startDate"
           name="startDate" bs-datepicker autocomplete="off"
           id="startDP"
           is-open="openDatePickerFlags.start"
           ng-click="openDatePickerFlags.start = !openDatePickerFlags.start"
           ng-readonly='true'
           show-button-bar='false'
           style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer;">
           <span class="add-on calender-icon" ng-click="openDatePickerFlags.start = !openDatePickerFlags.start; $event.stopPropagation()">
           <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></em>
           </span>
```

The code has become highly convoluted but basically I don't want to give user the option to type into the textbox which is why I am setting the readonly attribute and the style is provided to make sure that the textbox doesn't become grayed out. There is a similar input field for 'endDate'
I have been stuck on this problem for a long time now and any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this option in the document
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#todayhighlight

You can use this option like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/common.css">
        <script src="assets/common.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                $('input').datepicker({
                   todayHighlight: true
                }).datepicker('show');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body data-capture="input, .datepicker">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="03/03/2013">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```